# Remove Parts of a String PHP

Tags: php

I have a string which looks like this

`'a:1:{i:1;s:10:"username";}'`

I would like to remove everything but the username. The `a:1:{i:1;s:10:` part may change but the `;}` should not. Is there a way I can remove everything but the username part?

Comment: What is the string? It's not exactly valid json.

Comment: is user name between double quotes and is their any other double quotes in this string

Comment: @DaveChen Its serialized array.

Answer (score 5):

That is a serialized PHP array. Unserialize it with [`unserialize`](http://php.net/unserialize), then access the first array index.

Comment: It's an invalid serialized array :)

Comment: @FelixKling Cheater, you added two characters! :)

Comment: @netiul: Ha, I just copied Gedrox code and didn't notice that. In any case, I assume that `username` is just a placeholder (in the question) for the actual username in the array.

Comment: @FelixKling I think you're right! He probably replaced his username with the string "username" and didn't change s:10 into s:8.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$data = unserialize('a:1:{i:1;s:10:"usernamexx";}');
$username = $data[1];
```